# Why am I not receiving codes from IR receiver over the serial monitor?

Tags: arduino-uno, ir

I'm using the [Keyes Infrared Receiver Module](http://tinkbox.ph/sites/tinkbox.ph/files/downloads/Keyes%20-%20Infrared%20Receiver%20Module%20.pdf) on an Arduino Uno R3 with the [IRemote library](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote) included and running the `IRrecvDemo` example sketch included in the library.

I wired the IR receiver incorrectly the first time I ran the program. I wired the data pin to 5V and wired the Vcc pin on the module to the digital I/O pin. The ground was wired correctly.

Did I destroy the IR receiver by doing this? There was no noticeable overheating.

I corrected the wiring and tried again but still nothing over the serial monitor while pushing buttons on the IR remote that came with it. I wondered if the issue was with the remote so I hooked up a IR LED to flash using the following code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;

IRsend irsend;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
}

void loop()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {   //// for statement controls IR LED
    irsend.sendSony(0xa90, 12);   
    delay(40);
    if (irrecv.decode(&results))    //// if statement controls the receiver
    {
     Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
     irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
    }
  }
}
```

Nothing showed up on the serial monitor. However, the LED on the IR receiver module began flashing when the receiver was exposed to the IR LED, leading me to believe that I did not destroy the module when I wired it incorrectly.

Update:

I took the IR led and simply lit it with a coin cell battery and the IR receiver detected it and sent data over serial monitor. The remote powered by that same coin cell battery will not trigger the IR receiver. Can I conclude that this is a problem with the remote?

Comment: What is transmitting here? Are you sending from a remote?

Comment: @Nick Gammon Yes,the IR receiver came with a remote. I also have a simple IR LED that I set up just to see if the receiver would recognize it and send data over serial monitor. Neither worked.

Comment: I'm just wondering why your posted sketch has an `irsend` in it. What is the point of that?

Comment: Just shining an IR led on the module, **shouldn't** trigger the receiver, as it requires 38kHz modulated IR-light. So that's very suspicious.  I'd also check the remote by shining it towards a camera (e.g. the iPhone front camera, as it doesn't have an IR filter). Or just use the remote from your TV.

Comment: @Nick Gammon The posted code both sends IR signals using the IR led and receives the signals. The posted code is was for testing the receiver with the IR led. The code that I'd like to ultimately use is the `IRrecvDemo` sketch from the library to be used with a remote.

Comment: First, you can harvest this IR ASK receiver from almost any discarded entertainment equipment.  Second, as @Gerben said, you need a modulated signal.  A constant IR source (like the sun for example) should do nothing. Next, there are many ASK code variations.  Try several remotes.  Lastly, the camera trick should work with almost any CCD type camera.  I use my phone for this all the time.